# Why does my assertthrows-test gives a error, but runs anyway?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I am using Java11 and test with Junit5. I tray to test what the methode does with a NullPointer

My Test looks like this:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Test von isWellSorted-Nullstring")
void TestIsWellSortedNull() {
    String[] seq = null;
    assertThrows(NullPointerException.class,
            ()->{
                taskOr.isWellSorted(seq);
            });
        }
```

And my methode looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean isWellSorted(String[] sequenz){
    for(int i=0; i<sequenz.length-1;i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<order.length;j++) {
            if((j==order.length-1)&&(!sequenz[i].equals(order[j][0]))) {
                return false;
            }
            if(!sequenz[i].equals(order[j][0])) {
                continue;
            }
            if(sequenz[i+1].equals(order[j][1])) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And I get this Error, but the Code is still executable:

Inferred type 'T' for type parameter 'T' is not within its bound; should extend 'java.lang.Throwable'

Comment: Where do you see this error message?

Comment: In Intelliji it says in the Tab Problems and it has a red underlining

Comment: Then we need the full information to replicate it: Source including imports and Gradle/Maven file.